# Catching exception in async Task which returns value

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm working on a .NET Core app which uses Google Sheets Api. I'm using async tasks to avoid freezing guis. My trouble starts here. These async tasks connect Google Sheets and return some values. One of tasks:

```
public async Task<String> KullaniciBilgileriniAl()
    {
        String range = "Kullanici Bilgileri";
        SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest request = this.service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, range);
        ValueRange response = await Task.Run(() => request.Execute());
        IList<IList<Object>> values = response.Values;
        String DataKullaniciAdi = (String) values[1][0];
        String DataSifre = (String)values[1][1];
        return DataKullaniciAdi + DataSifre;
    }
```

What i'm trying to do is catch exceptions if there's no internet connection. If there's no connection, errors accure on this line:

```
ValueRange response = await Task.Run(() => request.Execute());
```

I've tried add this line into try-catch statement like that:

```
try
{
    ValueRange response = await Task.Run(() => request.Execute());
    IList<IList<Object>> values = response.Values;
    String DataKullaniciAdi = (String)values[1][0];
    String DataSifre = (String)values[1][1];
    return DataKullaniciAdi + DataSifre;
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

but tasks run on different threads. So it didn't work.

In summary, i need to catch any exception which accures in Task.Run() function. How can i do that?

Comment: *"So it didn't work"* <== You mean that the exception was not caught, or that it was caught but nothing was written in the debug console? What exactly is happening? Your code should work as expected IMHO.

Comment: Exception occured in another thread( where request.execute() is) and my code stopped. It wasn't handled by try-catch statement. My IDE marked on request.execute() function. @TheodorZoulias

Comment: Ahh, so it seems that it's not a problem of your application. It's a problem of debugging your application. If you run your application without the debugger attached (with Ctrl+F5), does it work as expected?

Comment: Yes, it's about debugging. Thank you a thousand times ! You saved me creating a lot of  exception handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well first of all remove `Task.Run` as it serves no purpose. You are create a task to run a synchronous method which is not needed. However, if you really want to keep it there for whatever reason, catch the exception within the task:

```
ValueRange response = await Task.Run(() => {

    try {
        return request.Execute();
    } catch Exception(Exception e){
        return null;
    }
});
```

Comment: You could also rethrow the exception from the catch block to make the main thread aware of this and take action.